# Back to views search result

Tags: 7, views

View search results gives node list based on exposed filters applied when making the search.

After user picks a result (node) and reads it there is no easy way to get him back to search results.

Exposed filters are "remembered", but the option to click back in browser does not seem user friendly, so i am looking for a module to do this. Is there any ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check the selected answer here [How to provide back link to page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90166/how-to-provide-back-link-to-page) just to confirm if you really want this kind of functionality and it also suggests some options that you can do and it's "non-recommended" level.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep, i only want to get back to views result page without using back button. Solutions on your link are close but i am not sure how to implement it. Also all answers there from 2013, so maybe some solution came up in meantime.